# how to use playwright to achieve automatically login into website by clicking button in electron

Tags: javascript, electron, playwright

```html
//index.html
<div class="main">
      <div class="account_list" id="account_list">
        <div>xx</div>
        <div><button class='login' id='login0'>login</button></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

```js
//account data
var account = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('account')) || [
    {
        name: 'xxx',
        unifiedCode: '91330783MA2HTW7E53',
        phoneNumber: '13805711234',
        password: 'jk123456'
    },
    {
        name: 'xxxx',
        unifiedCode: '91330783MA2HTW8D96',
        phoneNumber: '13805715869',
        password: 'jk123456'
    },
];
//login function in 'index.js'
loginButton.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
        return function() {
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(account[i]),
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        };
    })(i));
```

```js
//server.js
import express from 'express';
const { login } = require('./playwright'); // import the login function from your playwright.js file
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = 3000;
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
 const account = req.body;
 try {
 await login(account);
 res.send('Logged in');
 } catch (error) {
 console.error(error);
 res.status(500).send('Error logging in');
 }
});
app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```js
//playwright.js
import playwright from 'playwright';
async function login(account) {
 const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: false });
 const context = await browser.newContext();
 const page = await context.newPage();
 //my code to login the website
    await page.goto('https://etax.zhejiang.chinatax.gov.cn/zjgfdzswj/main/index.html');
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: '确定' }).click();
    await page.locator('#loginopen').click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder('统一社会信用代码/纳税人识别号').click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder('统一社会信用代码/纳税人识别号').fill(account.unifiedCode);
    await page.getByPlaceholder('居民身份证号码/手机号码/用户名').click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder('居民身份证号码/手机号码/用户名').fill(account.phoneNumber);
    await page.getByPlaceholder('个人用户密码').click();
    await page.getByPlaceholder('个人用户密码').fill(account.password);
    await page.locator('.handler').click();
    //const box = await page.locator('.handler').boundingBox();
    //{x: 608.6000366210938, y: 493.70001220703125, width: 54, height: 40}
    //drag_text 417*40
    const xmid_origin = 635;
    const ymid_origin = 513;
    await page.mouse.move(xmid_origin, ymid_origin);
    await page.mouse.down();
    const xmid_destination = 1028;
    const ymid_destination = 514;
    await page.mouse.move(xmid_destination, ymid_destination);
    await page.mouse.up();
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: '登录' }).click();
    await page.waitForTimeout(3000000);
}
module.exports = { login };
```

My full code is in "https://github.com/BakerSean168/Quickly-login"

I asked copilot in vscode, who told me to create 'playwright.js' 'server.js', I did, but it did not work. When I clicked the 'login' button, nothing happened. I asked copilot again, but it can not give useful information anymore. The information I found were about using playwright to test electron.

I hope that when I click on the login button, it will start calling playwright, open a browser and go to the website, and automatically log in.

What's the problem in my code?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXKSu.png)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.My full code is in "https://github.com/BakerSean168/Quickly-login". I'm a Beginner,and my main problem is how to use playwright to achieve the login function.

Comment: I've written the code for playwright,but how can i link it to the 'login' button.

Comment: There are two exemple account data in the 'index.js'.When you run the 'index.html',It will show two lines of accounts and buttons,and click 'login' button,nothing happen.
Can you tell me how to achieve the funtion? no matter changing the code given by copilot or another useful method

Comment: I've changed the code in 'body',should be the minimal example. I think it would be nice to click the button to bring up the playwright code

Comment: Can you replace `//my code to login the website` with the failing code attempt? Most of the code here isn't relevant since it's just front end UI that ultimately calls `login()`. `login()` is all that matters.

Comment: I've replaced it.But in my opinion, that's not the point, it should be that I didn't start the browser at all.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood. The problem is that the browser never opens when you click the UI button? I thought the issue was that Playwright was running but not logging you in. I'd still isolate the problem a bit clearer: if the request to the server goes through, then the UI isn't relevant. If the login code isn't relevant, you can remove it. The first step is to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: I don't know what's going on in the process of the server request, which is why I'm asking for help.I think this method can not call the playwright script.
So another method that could call the script is ok.
Also, I don't know if it's important, I just want to use it as a native software.

Comment: Can you show me a demo about how to call a playwright script as a function in js?

Comment: Maybe the confusion is using `module.exports`, which is Common JS rather than `export {login}`.

Comment: I modified it, but it didn't work.

Comment: I test whether it posts the account to '/login',and it shows 404.What's the reason?
I've taken a screenshot in the 'body'.